# ' - ' being converted to â€? while reading from json using json reader

Tags: android, json

I read a json file which contains some telephone numbers. Something like this:
    "number" : "416‐736‐5088"

I parse it using JsonReader it and save it into a list.

```
private void populateOfficeList() throws IOException {
    officeList.clear();
    InputStream in = null;
    JsonReader jsonReader = null;
    try {
        in = openFileInput(OFFICE_JSON);    
        System.out.println("got in " + in);
        jsonReader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8"));
        readofficeListMessageArray(jsonReader, officeList);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        jsonReader.close();
        in.close();
    }

}
```

Everything works fine. Its parsed and saved properly. However when i fetch these numbers for display,they get displayed like this:
    416â€?736â€?5217

I am already using UTF-8 for conversion. How do I get rid of these characters â€?

Comment: Yes, Thank you. That solved my problem. I already had a file saved in UTF-8 but I was first storing it in the internal memory and then reading it from there. I used UTF-8 while storing in internal memory too. That resolved it.

Comment: If I successfully answered your question, can you accept it as the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the wonderful world of character encoding. Make sure the file you're reading is saved in UTF-8 also.